# unset vs. session_unset doesnt work properly

Tags: php

When i want to echo data stored in session and then unset specific session... nothing happens. When i use session_unset(specific session) it destroys all sessions. Any ideas?

```
function danger($text)
{
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'>
    <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>×</a>" . $text . "</div>";
}

public function success($text)
{
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'>
    <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>×</a>" . $text . "</div>";
}

function flash($session)
{
    return $session;
    unset($session);
}
```

usage:

```
function checkErrors()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['login_error']))
    {
        return danger(flash($_SESSION['login_error']));
    } elseif (isset($_SESSION['login_true']))
    {
        return success(flash($_SESSION['login_true']));
    }
}
```

Comment: the code after return statement at your flash function never be executed, so your session will never be deleted. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478126/code-after-a-return-statement-in-a-php-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add temporary variable then unset your variable, like below :

```
function flash($session)
{
    $temp = $session;
    unset($session);
    return $temp;
}
```

And your function should be :

```
function danger($text)
{   $display = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'>
    <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>×</a>" . $text . "</div>";
    return $display;
}

public function success($text)
{
    $display = "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'>
    <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>×</a>" . $text . "</div>";
    return $display;
}
```

Comment: i wonder your success and danger function should return the string rather than echo them directly. See my updated answer

Comment: Yes its works! cool, thanks, but can you explain me what i did wrong?